# .NET Change the owner of an instance of a class (object) at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, class, runtime, instance

Is it possible in .NET C# to change the owner of an object at runtime?

For example:

```
class abc {
     MyClass ClassInstance = new MyClass();
     AnotherClass AnotherClassInstance = new AnotherClass();
     // Some how set the owner of "AnotherClassInstance" to "ClassInstance"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add an attribute or object to an instance of a class"? An instance of a class is by definition an object, so what are you exactly referring to?

Comment: Another way of putting it is how can I set the parent of an instance of a class

Comment: Sorry, this is still confusing. A *class* has a parent (the one it inherits from), but an instance of a class -- or an object -- has an *owner* (the object holding a reference to it)... I'm not sure what you mean by "the parent of an instance of a class"...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm rubbish at explaining things. How can I set the owner of an instance of a class, so I have my object, how can I set the owner of that object at runtime? Hopefully that will make sense

Comment: What do you mean by "owner of an instance"?

Comment: The owner, the "object holding a reference to it"

Comment: Now, if I understand this correctly, the question makes sense, but it's rather impractical: If you have an object A, you can't really expect to find all other objects B, C, D, etc. that happen to have a reference to it, without holding a reference to those inside A. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Lambert Yes that's kind of what I mean. So let's say if I have Object1, Object2 and Object3. Object1 and Object2 are an instance of Class1, and Object3 is an instance of Class2. Now I could hold a reference to Object3 by putting "public Class2 Object3 = Form1.Object3" inside Class1, but then the Object3 reference would exist inside Object1 and Object2.

Comment: So how can I add and remove references to a single object (not the whole class) at runtime? So something on the lines of "SomeMethodToAddAReference(ObjectThatIWantToReference,ObjectThatIWantToAddTheReferenceTo,"New Reference Instance Name");"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by *change the owner* of an instance? .NET objects don't have *owners*, so it's really not clear what you want.

If you meant you want the `AnotherClass` class to always have a `MyClass` which is considered as its "owner" in the class' logic, then simply add a constructor to `AnotherClass` which would take a `MyClass` as a parameter and will keep this reference.

Like this:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    MyClass owner = null;

    public AnotherClass(MyClass owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```